# data rate with a FSK modulation

Tags: digital-communications

With a BPSK modulation the data rate is $D=\frac{1}{T_s}$ where $T_s$ is the symbol time. But for a BFSK modulation, how do we find the data rate?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the data rate in bits per second is the symbol rate times the number of bits per symbol; independent of the modulation used.

The *B* in both BPSK and BFSK stands for *binary*, so there is 1 bit per symbol, or 2 possible symbols (2 possible phases or frequencies depending on the case).

So the data rate in both cases is the same.